# Editing a Single Document Posted in Multiple Places Only Once

Tags: 2013

Is there a way to have the same document in multiple places within SharePoint (like two different folders) but have them link to the same document, so changes made to the document in one place are universal for the document in other folders? So the document doesn't have to be updated multiple times in multiple places?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in a couple of steps.

1. Add a content type "Link to Document" to your library. (To add content type you must enable the "Allow content type" option in the Advanced Settings.)
2. You will see the option "Link to Document" when you click "New" button.
   [image]
3. When you click this option, it will ask for document name and URL. After click "Ok" it will add a shortcut to the document.
4. You can open the document from the either places to make edits.

Answer (score 1):

You can do through OOB if I got your question. Here is the steps:

Specify a Send To destination in the document library where the source files (original versions) are located.

1-Make a note of the URL for the SharePoint library to which you want to be able to copy files.

2-If the library for which you want to specify a Send To destination is not already open, click its name on the Quick Launch.

If the name of your library does not appear, click View All Site Content, and then click the name of your library.

A-On the Settings menu  settings menu , click the settings for the type of library that you are opening.

For example, in a document library, click Document Library Settings.

3-Under General Settings, click Advanced settings.

4-In the Custom Send To Destination section, under Destination Name, type a brief name for the destination to which files will be copied. It is helpful to keep this name brief because the name appears after the Send To command on the shortcut menu for the library.

5-Under URL, type the Uniform Resource Locator (URL) for the SharePoint library to which you want to be able to copy files. For example, to copy to a specific document library or to a folder within a document library, type either: http://servername/sitename/libraryname or

Answer (score 0):

The send to function might be what you are looking for.  [Send to Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/specify-a-send-to-destination-for-a-library-f5db67a2-7ddb-48a9-a652-deada0e91c3a?ocmsassetid=ha010120850&correlationid=d0c24ae8-b2d3-4f47-89cc-8923dd4d890b&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us). This should maintain a source file that will be shown in the other libraries you have sent to.